# Способы вызова функций

Tags: php

Чем отличаются два вызова функций:

```
$headers = @get_headers($site);
```

**&&**

```
$headers = get_headers($site);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$headers = @get_headers($site);
```

если будут ошибки, то они не будут выведены на экран, во втором случае будут

Comment: Спасибо вам.